# Summing Course Credits with Business Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In order for a student to graduate high school with "emphasis" in a particular subject, they must complete at least one introductory course in a defined list that area of expertise, and three core courses. I am trying to show the number of credits a student has and can be used to assign a student an "emphasis". The problem is a student can take numerous introductory level classes that might apply to an area of expertise, but only one of them should count towards the total credits. Or visa-versa, they can't be assigned if they have four core courses but no introductory class. Here is my statement below. Everything about this is telling me it is a loop, but I understand that opening cursors is bad for performance, and there is a 't-sql' way of doing this most likely.

```
Select * From (Select ks.ks_id,
    ks.student_name,
    ks.current_grade_level, 
    cpp.title,
    ks.bldg_id, 
    Sum(cc.credits) as 'Sum of Credits Per Expertise' ,

From #KidsSilo as ks
    Inner Join cpp_courses as cc on cc.statecourse_id = ks.statecourse_id --- cpp_courses contains all the courses
    Inner Join #Cpp_expertise as cpp on cc.cpp_ID = cpp.cpp_id --- cpp_expertise contains all the Expertise' and the id link to each cpp_courses
        Where cpp.bldg_id = ks.bldg_id
            --And cc.course_level = 'X' -- Introductory, Would a nested Select Top 1 1 work for this piece?
            --And cc.course_level = 'C' -- Core classes

Group by
    ks.ks_id,
    cpp.title,
    ks.student_name, 
    ks.current_grade_level,
    ks.bldg_id) as t
Inner Join #Districts as d on d.bldg_id = t.bldg_id
order by t.bldg_id desc
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your sample code seems to have all sorts of irrelevant stuff like districts and buildings.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a courses table with:

- course id
- expertise
- level

And an enrollment table that has students in the courses, then I would expect a query like this:

```
select e.student_id, c.expertise
from enrollment e join
     courses c
     on e.course_id = c.course_id
group by e.student_id, c.expertise
having sum(case when level = 'introductory' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1 and
       sum(case when level = 'core' then 1 else 0 end) >= 3;
```

Your data model is very unclear, but perhaps this will help.

Comment: I will vote to close the question, as `having` does not seem to work. And I wasn't very clear in my design or question.

Comment: @christopherclark . . . This does exactly what your question asks.  Your data model is unclear, but the logic should be pretty similar.